# Hyperlink from excel/word to report in JasperReports Server

Tags: excel, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a problem with hyperlink from excel to a report in *JasperReports Server*, I have the following URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/jasperserver/flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&ParentFolderUri=/reports&reportUnit=/reports/ReportePorCampo&standAlone=true
```

I export my report to XLS or ODT format. I make click at the link and the browser show the login page, I put the login information but when I make click in login button, the report is not presented (appear the content of report directory but not the requested report).

On the other hand if I export the report to PDF format and I make click, effectly open the browser and appear the login page (normally as step from xls) but when I login in this case the report appear immediately. Why is this? if the link is the same, the difference is the software that execute the URL.